# Natural Analysis: a possible new field?

Tags: analysis, soft-question

I have studied real analysis for two years now, yet I often find that when applying it, (say to finding a path of shortest time) I often have to get solutions without closed forms (i.e. defined point by point) (especially when finding local minima of a functional) due to computational difficultly.

i.e., it seems that some applications of real analysis often end up with discrete approximations to a continuous system. Then it appears to me that we can analyze discrete functions (i.e. $f:\Bbb N^n \to\Bbb N^m$), like finding their minima and maxima, as opposed to real valued functions ($f:\Bbb R^n \to\Bbb R^m$).

Does anyone know what interesting results (if there are any) there are in the analysis of discrete functions? Or by what name this field is conventionally referred to?

Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: It seems like you are thinking of [Numerical Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis).

Comment: You might be interested in the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Maclaurin_summation) and related topics.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are interested in the following two fields:

1. [Integer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), which is exactly about optimization of integer-to-integer functions, or
2. [Numerical Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis), which is about the process of approximating maybe-messy problems efficiently and effectively.